# triggered button on form validation using vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have 4 different buttons and if each is clicked it needs to passe the validate function a name so I will know which button triggered the event. I need to get the input that was clicked and use different logic for each.

So I have this function that is being triggered for all the submit in the inputs but I cannot get the v-model for each.

```
<form v-if="loadingCount === 0" @submit.prevent="validateBeforeSubmit()" :error-hack="vErrors.any()" novalidate>

<v-btn color="primary" type="submit" data-test="full-encode-btn" :loading="savingCount > 0" :disabled="savingCount > 0">
Mapping Encode
</v-btn>

<v-btn v-model="encodeType" color="primary" type="submit" data-test="full-encode-btn"
 :loading="savingCount > 0" :disabled="savingCount > 0">
Decode </v-btn>

validateBeforeSubmit(scope, type) {
    const args = scope ? [scope] : [];
    const aa = console.log(type)
    this.$validator
        .validateAll(...args)
        .then(result => {
            if (!result) {
                const errorsLength = this.$validator.errors.items.length;
                this.showError(
                    `Url is empty: Please update it`
                );
                return;
            }
            //this.startEncodeDecode();
            this.cleanForm();
        })
        .catch(e => {
            console.error(e);
        });
}
```

Comment: Please create a [small demo](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for this using [codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue) to show the issue happening.

Comment: Why does your component need to pass the validate function a name? Typically what you would do is trigger validation on the form as described in the vuetify docs (or third party) and check all fields, why not that?

Comment: yes i need to know which button triggered the submit as there are 4 of them and my logic is different for each. so its important that i will know which triggered  validateBeforeSubmit function